# C++ Is it safe to test for NaN using cast to long?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, double, nan

As I understand it NaN's are represented by all 1's in the exponent part of a double's representation and non-zero fraction. (Info from [here](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html))

Is it safe to test for NaN using something like:

```
double num = 1.0;

// Do something to make num NaN

double* pointer = &num;
unsigned long long num2 = *((unsigned long long*)pointer);

if((unsigned long long)num2 == 0x7FF8000000000001)
{
    // Got a NaN
}
```

I hope that 0x7FF8000000000001 is the correct test.

Since the fraction has to be non-zero to represent a NaN, then I guess the fractional part of the double representation can by anything, so perhaps a more sophisticated test would be required, which converted the fractional part to 1, as shown in the number 0x7FF8000000000001. (Note the 1 on the end, in the fractional part.)

So, would something like this ever be safe to use?

Edit: As Mike mentioned, in the example I should have used a pointer to get the bits, I will make this change now...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366485/problems-casting-nan-floats-to-int ?

Comment: There are different kinds of NANs, and there is std::isnan...

Comment: That cast does a numeric conversion; you'd need to cast a reference or pointer to reinterpret the bits of the `double` as an integer type. As you say, you'd need to test that that fraction is non-zero, not equal to 1. `std::isnan` will test for NaN correctly and portably; I'd just use that.

Comment: The important part of what Mike mentioned is the use of `std::isnan`. I seen no reason not to use it.

Comment: Yes, in C++ use `std::isnan( )`, in C use `isnan( )`.

Answer (score 3):

Quite a few different 64-bit bit patterns mean `NaN` in floating-point.  Mike Seymour told you to use `isnan`, which is the readable way to check for `NaN`.  You can also use the floating-point comparison `x != x`, which fails only when `x` is `NaN`.

However, if you insist on doing it with bit patterns:

- The sign bit is irrelevant.
- The significand mustn't be zero; if it is, you have an infinity rather than a `NaN`.
- The biased exponent must be `0x7ff`; otherwise, you have a normal or subnormal floating-point number.

So I would suggest, again only if you insist on using bit patterns and tying yourself to your own nonportable code, something like the following ugly, unportable, untested snippet:

```
u64 xl = (u64 &)x;
u64 sig = xl & 0xfffffffffffffull;
if ((xl >> 52 & 0x7ff) == 0x7ff && sig != 0) return 1;
else return 0;
```

The high bit of the significand tells you whether you have a "quiet NaN" or a "signaling NaN."

Comment: The test `x != x` should be avoided. Some optimizing compilers will replace `x != x` by `false`.

Comment: @user763305: Which compilers?  Because it sounds like those compilers are broken.

Comment: I don't remember, but it has happened to me. It also depends on which compiler flags you use.

Comment: @user763305: Yeah, sometimes you need to work around broken compilers.  I can't imagine a compiler that deliberately miscompiles floating-point code in the name of "optimisation" would let very much of my code work, though.  You sure you weren't using `-ffast-math` or something like that?

Comment: I think it was the Intel C++ compiler for Windows with the flag -O3, the highest optimization level.