# Bounds checking a float from only an unsigned bit string

Tags: c, floating-point, bitstring

I am trying to return the result of casting a single precision float to an int just from its bit string. I correctly grab the sign bit, exponent and mantissa from the bit string but I am unsure how to ensure a float is in the range (0x80000000<float<0x7fffffff) solely from its bit string.

Additionally, I am confused when I should round the result to 0? It appears that casting to an int does round to 0, I just don't know when or why this occurs?

Here is my code so far:

```
int convertFloatToAnInt(unsigned f) {
//trying to return (inf)f
  int signBit = (f >> 31) & 1;
  int exponent = (f >> 23) & 0xFF;
  int mantissa = f & 0x7FFFFF;
  exponent = exponent - 127;
 
  int truncatedFloat = 0;
  //trucate based on the exponent with decimal at 23rd bit
  truncatedFloat = (mantissa>>(23-exponent));
    
  //add the implicit 1 back to the mantissa
  truncatedFloat |= (1<<exponent);

  //change the sign if needed
  if (signBit) {
    truncatedFloat = ~(truncatedFloat)+1;
  }

  return truncatedFloat;//(int)f
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this by hand?  `return (int)*(float*)&f;` will do the job.  And you should be able to tell just from the exponent whether the resulting integer fits in 32 bits.

Comment: @TimRoberts: The behavior of `(int)*(float*)&f;` is not defined by the C standard, and this should not be recommended. Defined ways to reinterpret bits including using a union and using `memcpy`, and compilers will commonly optimize these to efficient instructions.

Comment: Let's be honest.  He's experimenting.  The bitwise layout of a float is also not guaranteed.

Comment: @TimRoberts: Whether he is experimenting or not is irrelevant. The behavior of `(int)*(float*)&f` is not defined by the C standard, and it should not be recommended. There are defined ways to reinterpret the bits, and students should be taught the defined ways, not improper code.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume the IEEE 754 single-precision representation of `float` and 32-bit width for `int` and `unsigned` as indicated in the question.

The `int` has range [-2^31; 2^31-1].

The significand in the `float` is essentially a 24 bit value multiplied by 2^-23 (i.e. shifted 23 places to the right). This will fit within 31 bits if it is shifted at most 30 places to the left. Hence, if the exponent is at most 30, then the value will fit into an `int`. However, there is one case where the exponent is 31 which also fits: if the value is -2^31, i.e. the sign bit is set and the exponent is 31 and the mantissa is 0.

When doing the conversion, these checks must be made before doing the bit-shifting to avoid [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57617802/when-can-bit-shifting-cause-undefined-behaviour). Also, it must be checked if the mantissa should be shifted left or right since shifting a negative amount is undefined behaviour.

Thus an implementation could be:

```
int toInt(unsigned f)
{
  int signBit = (f >> 31) & 1;
  int exponent = (f >> 23) & 0xFF;
  int mantissa = f & 0x7FFFFF;
  exponent = exponent - 127;

  int result = 0;
  if(exponent >= 0)
  {
    if(exponent <= 30)
    { // The result is within range
      int mantissa1 = mantissa | (1u << 23);
      if(exponent <= 23)   // Need to shift right
        result = mantissa1 >> (23-exponent);
      else                 // Need to shift left
        result = mantissa1 << (exponent-23);  
      if(signBit) result = -result;
    }
    else
    { // Probably out of range, but check for -2^31
      if(exponent == 31 && signBit && mantissa == 0)
        result = -(1u<<31);
      else
        printf("Error: out of range");
    }
  }
  // else the absolute value is less than 1, so the result is 0
  return result;
}
```

Note: calling this function requires passing the bit pattern of a float as an unsigned. This can be done as follows:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    float x = -pow(2.0, 31);
    unsigned xBits;
    memcpy(&xBits, &x, 4);
    printf("%d, %d", (int)x, toInt(xBits));

    return 0;
}
```

It is important to notice that `(int)x` will be [undefined behaviour if `x` does not fit in an `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30851490/casting-double-to-integer-when-is-it-undefined-behaviour). The function `toInt()` will not have undefined behaviour for any value of `x`. However, of course, `toInt()` relies heavily on implementation-defined behavior such as the representation of `float`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `float` uses that format, you can safely perform the type conversion using a union.

```c
uint32_t u = ...;

float f = ( ( union { uint32_t u; float f; } ){ .u = u } ).f;
```

`memcpy` could also be used.

Comment: Hmm, a bit light on explanation, 'eh - but dead on `:)`

Comment: This answer assumes `float` is 32-bit (common) and the endian of integers and FP are the same (common).

Answer (score 0):

> I am unsure how to ensure a float is in the range (0x80000000<float<0x7fffffff) solely from its bit string.

You can use `0 <= f && f < 0x4F000000u || 0x80000000u <= f && f <= 0xCF000000u`.

The encodings of IEEE-754 binary32 floating-point numbers are in ascending order for non-negative numbers and descending order for negative numbers. I assume you are using binary32 for `float` and you have the bit strings in the proper order.

The bit patterns for +0 and +2<sup>31</sup> are 00000000<sub>16</sub> and 4F000000<sub>16</sub>. So a `float` is in [+0, +2<sup>31</sup>) iff its bit string is in [00000000<sub>16</sub>, 4F000000<sub>16</sub>).

The patterns for −0 and −2<sup>31</sup> are 80000000<sub>16</sub> and CF000000<sub>16</sub>. So a `float` is in [−2<sup>31</sup>, −0] iff its bit string is in [80000000<sub>16</sub>, CF000000<sub>16</sub>].

> It appears that casting to an int does round to 0, I just don't know when or why this occurs?

Conversion of a floating-point type to an integer type is specified by C 2018 6.3.1.4 1, and it says the value is truncated toward zero.