# Why does a nan of type <class 'numpy.float64'> return -9223372036854775808 as an int64?

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I came across some behavior that I find odd and replicated it. simply, why does

```
np.int64(np.float64(np.nan))
```

output

```
-9223372036854775808
```

(as pointed out in comments, yes this is -2^63, the maximum negative value for a two-sided int64)

In case it is relevant or of interest, my original use case was looking at dataframe indices of type np.float64 and converting to np.int64 (I don't normally nest types for no reason as in the simplified example above).
Starting with an example dataframe:

```
    0   1
NaN 1   2
1.0 3   4
NaN 5   6
```

then running:

```
print(df.index.values[0])
print(type(df.index.values[0]))
print(df.index.values[0].astype(np.int64))
print(type(df.index.values[0].astype(np.int64)))
```

prints:

```
nan
<class 'numpy.float64'>
-9223372036854775808
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

However, using python types you can't convert float nan to int:

```
print(np.nan)
print(type(np.nan))
print(np.nan.astype(np.int64))
```

out:

```
nan
<class 'float'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-130-0d779433eac7> in <module>
      1 print(np.nan)
      2 print(type(np.nan))
----> 3 print(np.nan.astype(np.int64))

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

Although in practice I was able to just change the nans to a value I knew would not be a key (0) - I was curious why do class np.float64 types behave this way?

Comment: Integer values don't have a NaN value, so casting a NaN may be undefined, especially if the underlying library is implemented in C.

Comment: Doing the conversion in Python would actually be `import math; int(math.nan)`, which leads to a ValueError: Python intercepts the invalid conversion.

Comment: is it a hunch that it is numpy's C utilization that causes it or do you know for sure? (just curious as it sounds like a plausible cause). I wasn't able to easily find a reference to this issue elsewhere searching google. (I thought even searching that large negative integer might do it, but nothing).

Comment: Related NumPy issue: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4592 . This may be a bug in NumPy: `numpy.float64(numpy.nan)` throws a ValueError, `numpy.int64(numpy.float64(numpy.nan))` yields the minimum value for i64 (and similar for i32, u32, u64).

Comment: It's not a C issue per se (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366485/problems-casting-nan-floats-to-int for C (non)behaviour of such conversions), but it definitely looks like it is a NumPy issue.

Comment: Note https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support ; I'm not sure if this also works for indices of a series or dataframe.

Comment: @00 ahhh, i should have known that it was -2^63, so i guess somewhere along the way numpy rolls over and for some reason goes negative... interesting. I wonder if there was a reason for this or if its an actual bug. Seems a bit dangerous to not handle for this.

Comment: I don't think Numpy "rolls over" (why would it stop right after that?): I think it tries to pick a unique value that hopefully isn't too common, which is the lowest value allowed. Of course, that is just my guess, I haven't looked under the hood, and this choice fails for the unsigned types, where you end with 0, which is (likely) a very common value.

Comment: Note that going from NaN to float to int is a circuitous way of (attempting to) converting a nan to an integer, so I'm not surprised this case isn't covered that well (and thus shows buggy behaviour).

Comment: Amendment to my above comment: your original use case, converting a Pandas index NaN value directly to an integer, does seem to avoid the extra step. I was initially looking at the NumPy case all the way at the top of the question. Though it may be possible that Pandas performs an additional cast under the hood.

Comment: You may also want to compare `df.index.astype(np.int64)` versus `df.index[0].astype(np.int64)`.

Comment: doing the entire index versus one value yields the same result (all nan become -2^63), that was just for the example i focussed on one value. I was looking at the pandas docs too as it said they allowed for nan to int but was unable to get it to work. (i have version >1.0) not the end of the world though as my bandaid fix will be fine for this adhoc use case.

Comment: Hmm, for me, `df.index.astype(np.int64)` throws a ValueError. You only get -2^63 if you do `df.index.values.astype(np.int64)` instead.

Comment: ah, you are right, my code for that was `np.int64(df.index.values)`... which returns values. Bizarre.

I also found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366485/problems-casting-nan-floats-to-int/66533605#66533605

Which suggests you were probably correct in saying it is something to do with C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `df.index.values` is a numpy array:

```
Out[34]: array([nan,  1., inf])
In [35]: a.dtype
Out[35]: dtype('float64')
```

Arrays have a `astype` method, and the developers chose to convert special floats like `nan` to some sort of integer (or as discussed allow the compiler/processor do it).  The alternative would have been to raise an error.

```
In [36]: b=a.astype(int)
In [37]: b
Out[37]: array([-9223372036854775808,                    1, -9223372036854775808])
In [38]: b.dtype
Out[38]: dtype('int64')
```

`np.int32`, `np.uint16` etc produce different values.

An object created with `np.float64` function is a lot like a 0d array - it has many of the same attributes and methods, including `astype`:

```
In [39]: np.float64(np.nan)
Out[39]: nan
In [40]: np.array(np.nan)
Out[40]: array(nan)
In [41]: Out[39].astype(int)
Out[41]: -9223372036854775808
In [42]: Out[40].astype(int)
Out[42]: array(-9223372036854775808)
```

`np.nan` on the other hand is a Python float object, and does not have a `astype` method.

And the `python` `int` doesn't like to do it either:

```
In [52]: int(np.nan)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-52-03e21f51ddd3>", line 1, in <module>
    int(np.nan)
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

Answer (score -1):

`astype()` is a Pandas function. When you work with np.nan, you cannot use Pandas functions. rather use `int(np.nan)`

Comment: it is the same result if I do `np.int64(np.float64(np.nan))` which doesn't touch pandas: `-9223372036854775808`

Comment: You definitely can use np.nan when working with Pandas; Pandas uses a lot of NumPy under the hood, and will try to work with it properly as much as possible.