# There are 2 kinds of NaN: signaling_NaN, quiet_NaN, and... NAN itself?

Tags: c++, nan

I always thought there were 2 kinds of NaN's: quiet and signaling.

But then I realized the `NAN` macro evaluates to *neither*.

In Visual C++, `std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN()` is displayed as `1.#QNAN000`.
In Visual C++, `std::numeric_limits<float>::signaling_NaN()` is displayed as `1.#QNAN000`.
Yet also in Visual C++, `NAN` is displayed as `-1.#IND0000`... which is neither of the above.

1. What kind of NaN, then, is the `NAN` constant? Is it signaling or nonsignaling?
2. When should I use `NAN` instead of the others, when should I avoid it, and why?

Comment: There are more than two NaN values. In particular, there are millions of signaling NaNs and millions of quiet NaNs. [They print in different ways](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/02/21/10395734.aspx).

Comment: @RaymondChen: I think you missed the phrase *"**kinds** of NaN"* in my question which I repeated 3 times. But thanks for the link, I'll take a look at your blog to see if it's talking about "kinds" of NaNs.

Comment: `quiet_NaN()` returns *a* quiet NaN, but there are others. The `NAN` macro returns a different quiet NaN. Saying that NaN is neither `quiet_NaN()` nor `signaling_NaN()` doesn't mean that it's not either. It's just a quiet NaN that is a different quiet NaN from the one returned by `quiet_NaN`. If you wanted to know whether NAN is signaling or not, [the documentation says it is quiet](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/NAN/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You machine does not have a signaling `NaN`. I presume the `Q` in `#QNAN` stands for Quiet. Check `numeric_limits::has_signaling_NaN`. As for `signaling_NaN`, the standard says this:

> Meaningful for all specializations for which has_signaling_NaN != false. Required in specializations
>   for which is_iec559 != false.

Therefore, it may be required yet meaningless… the natural thing to do is supply a quiet NaN instead.

I haven't found an authoritative resource for `QNAN` vs `IND`, but they appear to both be quiet NaNs. There are potentially millions of different NaNs, one for each mantissa value. If I were to guess, `IND` may be like an error code for an *ind*‍eterminate value, e.g. 0/0. Not really an appropriate choice for a generic `NAN` macro, but they might have been stuck with it after defining the C numeric binding that way.

Comment: So they're the same type of NAN, just with a different string representation? +1 thanks

Comment: @Mehrdad Since there are only two "types", signaling and non-signaling, and your results seem to indicate signaling doesn't exist on your platform, I guess you could say they're the same type. According to [Eric Postpischil](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10400536/153285), you hit the nail on the head: they differ only in string representation.